# Download html page with right encoding by webclient

Tags: c#, encoding, webclient

I download a page with encoding: "usa-ascii" but I get wrong character. why??

```
WebClient wb = new WebClient();
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("US-ASCII");
wb.Encoding = enc;
byte[] by = wb.DownloadData(link);
string htmlDoc = enc.GetString(by);
```

but I get: **Pr?z** instead of: **Präz**.

Html of my [link](http://www.rosenkranz-elektronik.de/usedline.htm): (charest=us-ascii)

```
<html debug="true">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"/>
</head>
...................
```

What is wrong???

p.s. I tryed encoding utf-8 and it didn't work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

US-ASCII does not have that character, so the page contains an invalid character (for the defined charset). Your code isn't wrong, the problem is that US-ASCII won't suffice for characters like `ä`.

US-ASCII data table: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aASCII_Code_Chart.svg)

Comment: If so: 1. why ascii work good in the webPage. 2. why utf-8 not work for me??

Comment: I don't know, but I'll try: 1) Your browser could be fixing it behind the scenes. 2) Your page may not have been saved as UTF-8 when it was created - I would need the web page to find that out.

Comment: I added my link to the question. (hyper link in the word "link"). see line number 6. column number 3.

Comment: First thing: your HTML is broken. It doesn't have a <HTML> start tag, and the <META> tag should be enclosed in <HEAD> tags.

Comment: Second: the ä in question is the byte E4 (I saw in a hex-editor). Probably the page was saved in ISO-8859-1, and Firefox is using that charset to display it, and that's why it's displayed incorrectly. Anyway, my answer still stands.